# Is it possible to read pdf which is opened online and read the text contents of it and store it in a file?

Tags: python-3.x

I am looking to read a pdf and extract the text from it. The pdf is present in one of the url's and I don't wish to download it. I wish to read it on-the-go from the internet. Is this even possible?

I tried using 'Tika' but it doesn't really work. It gave me error:

> 2019-08-29 15:39:15,416 [MainThread  ] [WARNI]  Tika server returned
>   status: 500 {'status': 500}

```
from tika import parser
URL_path = "http://www.---path to .pdf"    
raw = parser.from_file(URL_path)
print(raw)
```

Comment: So you want to read the content of a pdf file from online link? And for that you are writing a python script ?

Comment: The "500" suggests that there is a problem with your request. Is the URL definitely correct? The server expects a GET request? If you copy the exact URL from your code and paste it in an incognito window in your browser, does it work?

Comment: @saintamh , Thanks for your reply. Yes, the url is absolutely right. I tried opening it in incognito mode and it opens a PDF

Comment: @mishsx Thanks for the reply, Yes, trying to write a script that would read an online PDF and extract text from it

Comment: I mean but why tho? Unless you are doing this for a bulk amount of URL, it always makes sense to download it and scan it using an OCR library

Comment: @mishsx, you are right. I am doing it for more than 100 URLS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i grab pdf links from website with Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6222911/how-can-i-grab-pdf-links-from-website-with-python-script)

Comment: @mishsx, See , i don't need the PDF links. I need the pdf data which can be extracted to a text file.

Comment: Well, thats one part of the problem but the other part is already answered here -->https://stackoverflow.com/a/45480440/7841468